# Qual a diferença entre o space-around e o space-evenly?

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber a diferença dessas 2 propriedades `justify-content:space-around;` e `justify-content:space-evenly`

Answer (score 2):

A diferença básica está na distribuição dos espaços:

- `space-around`: pega todo o espaço que sobrar na linha e distribui igualmente entre os elementos, deixando o spaço igual em toda a linha;
- `space-evenly`: o espaço é distribuido igualmente entre cada elemento adjacente, ou seja, um ao lado do outro, com exceção do primeiro e último:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
 }

li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 2px red;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 10px 0;
}


.lista-space-around { 
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
.lista-space-around li {
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.lista-space-evenly { 
  justify-content: space-evenly; 
}

.lista-space-evenly li { 
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<ul class="lista-space-evenly">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista-space-around">
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Veja que na primeira linha todos os espaços entre os elementos são iguais e na segunda já são iguais entre dois elementos, e diferente entre o primeiro e o último

Comment: Posso editar a resposta e colocar uma ilustração?

Comment: tem o exemplo já, só clicar em executar

Comment: Obrigado Amigos!

Comment: caso a resposta seja útil, não esqueça de votar :)

Answer (score -1):

Segundo o MDN:

justify-content:

space-around: Os itens são distribuídos uniformemente dentro do contêiner de alinhamento ao longo do eixo principal. O espaçamento entre cada par de itens adjacentes é o mesmo. O espaço vazio antes do primeiro e depois do último item é igual a metade do espaço entre cada par de itens adjacentes.

Ou seja: Considere que todos os elementos do eixo principal possuem um espaço vazio "margem" (com o mesmo tamanho) que os envolve "around". Como esse espaço é igual para todos os elementos, consequentemente, os elementos adjacentes (leia-se: internos) terão um espaço entre si dobrado, pois essas "margens" se somam. O que não ocorre, logicamente, com espaço vazio antes do primeiro e depois do último item.

space-evenly: Distribuição uniforme de espaço vazio:
Os itens são distribuídos uniformemente dentro do contêiner de alinhamento ao longo do eixo principal. O espaçamento entre cada par de itens adjacentes, a borda inicial principal e o primeiro item, e a borda final principal e o último item, são todos exatamente iguais.